# Exoplayer, play an audio stream and a video stream synchronously?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

I am using the following code to play a stream (which has both a video and an audio). But what if I want a video stream and a separate audio stream for the video stream at the same time synchronously? For example, suppose there are

- https://someserver.com/video1/video.mp4
- https://someserver.com/video1/audio.mp3

Both `video.mp4` and `audio.mp3` belong to `video1` and have the same length, 1:23:34. Can I play `video.mp4` and `audio.mp3` synchronously as if they were one stream, with one ExoPlayer? The user must be able to pause/play/seek, and the same action should be applied to both streams.

If not, and I have to use two ExoPlayers, one for video and one for audio, how can I synchronise the audio and the video?

```
    var uri = Uri.parse(url);
    var df = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(url);
    var ms = ExtractorMediaSource(uri, df, DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
    exoPlayer.playWhenReady=true;
    exoPlayer.prepare(ms);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can! This is done in ExoPlayer [by creating a `MergingMediaSource`](https://exoplayer.dev/media-sources.html#side-loading-a-subtitle-file). The example in the link merges a video source with a subtitle source but it's even easier for audio and video:

```
MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...)
    .createMediaSource(videoUri);
MediaSource audioSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(...)
    .createMediaSource(audioUri);

MergingMediaSource mergedSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, audioSource);
```

Comment: If I use this method to play `video.mp4` and `audio.mp3` concurrently, can I replace the `audio.mp3` with `audio2.mp3` on-the-fly?

Comment: I have tried this one but not working.. I have one audio.mp3 and video.mp4 which I need to play both at a time but the player only plays the video.